# how to avoid scientific number format using float datatype in mysql?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring

I am using mysql as my backend DB and hibernate and spring as my Front end. I am using float type in many of the tables, which accept only upto seven digits after then the value is saved in scientific number format which is a big problem, i cant used double as it will refelct most of the tables.

I have tried using decimal format but it didn't work

```
protected void initBinder(HttpServletRequest request, ServletRequestDataBinder binder) 
throws Exception{
    CustomDateEditor dateEditor = new CustomDateEditor(new format("dd/MM/yyyy"), true);
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class,null, dateEditor);

    DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat();
    DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
    symbols.setDecimalSeparator('.');
    decimalFormat.setDecimalFormatSymbols(symbols);
    decimalFormat.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);

    binder.registerCustomEditor(Float.class, 
    new CustomNumberEditor(Float.class, decimalFormat, true));
}
```

Can any one tell how to avoid the scientific notation in float without changing its type.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "scientific number format using float", you only see scientific notation applied when you (implicitly or explicitly) change the representation of the data, most likely to a character representation.

Hibernate maps data stored in a database to java data types - it doesn't do any conversion which would cause the representation of the number to change to scientific notation.

[Java.text.DecimalFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) is a tool for converting numbers into strings. If you want to change the format of the string it generates, then tell it what format you want to use. e.g.

```
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat('###,###,###,###,###.0#');
```

BTW, you shouldn't use floats for currency values.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i tried your method but still it didn't works for me.    Here is the code                                             DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("###,###,###,###,###.0#");  
  binder.registerCustomEditor(Float.class, new CustomNumberEditor(Float.class, decimalFormat, true));